# Writing an object to python file

Tags: python, file-io

I have a following code:

```
 matrix_file = open("abc.txt", "rU")
 matrix = matrix_file.readlines()
 keys = matrix[0]
 vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
 ea=open("abc_format.txt",'w')
 ea.seek(0)
 ea.write(vals)
 ea.close()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

How do I buffer the output and what data type is the variable `vals`?

Comment: `vals` is a list, not a string. What output did you expect to be written?

Comment: instead of 'w' try 'wb'

Comment: Consider [pickle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to persist objects in file.

Comment: @SaraSantana: I tried wb, but it didn't work either

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I want to output the whole matrix minus the first row and the first column.

Comment: @SaraSantana: that's not very helpful. Binary files don't know how to store arbitrary objects either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vals` is a list. If you want to write a list of strings to a file, as opposed to an individual string, use `writelines`:

```
 ea=open("abc_format.txt",'w')
 ea.seek(0)
 ea.writelines(vals)
 ea.close()
```

Note that this will not insert newlines for you (although in your specific case your strings already end in newlines, as pointed out in the comments). If you need to add newlines you could do the following as an example:

```
 ea=open("abc_format.txt",'w')
 ea.seek(0)
 ea.writelines([line+'\n' for line in vals])
 ea.close()
```

Comment: Since the input was read with `readlines()`, the newlines have not been removed and don't need to be re-added.

Comment: It worked! except now the matrix in the output file has a tab at the beginning of each line, can you tell me how can I override those tabs

Comment: If it has a tab, you put it there.

Comment: You can write lines with leading tabs stripped with `ea.writelines([line.lstrip('\t') for line in vals])`

Answer (score 0):

First of all instead of opening and closing the file separately you can use [*with statement*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) that does the job automatically.and about the Error,as it says the `write` method only accepts character buffer object so you need to convert your list to a string.

For example you can use `join` function that join the items within an iterable object with a specific delimiter and return a concatenated string.

```
with open("abc.txt", "rU") as f,open("abc_format.txt",'w') as out:
   matrix = f.readlines()
   keys = matrix[0]
   vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
   out.write('\n'.join(vals))
```

Also as a more pythonic way as the file objects are iterators you can do it in following code and get the first line with calling its `next` method and pass the rest to `join` function :

```
with open("abc.txt", "rU") as f,open("abc_format.txt",'w') as out:
   matrix = next(f)
   out.write('\n'.join(f))
```

Comment: Whats the problem with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "write" objects to files. Rather, use the `pickle` module:

```
matrix_file = open("abc.txt", "rU")
matrix = matrix_file.readlines()
keys = matrix[0]
vals = [line[1:] for line in matrix[1:]]
#pickling begins!
import pickle
f = open("abc_format.txt")
pickle.dump(vals, f) #call with (object, file)
f.close()
```

Then read it like this:

```
import pickle
f = open("abc_format.txt")
vals = pickle.load(f) #exactly the same list
f.close()
```

You can do this with any kind of object, your own or built-in. You can only write strings and bytes to files, python's `open()` function just opens it like opening notepad would.

To answer your first question, `vals` is a list, because anything in `[operation(i) for i in iterated_over]` is a list comprehension, and list comprehensions make lists. **To see what the type of any object is, just use** the `type()` function; e.g. `type([1,4,3])`

Examples: https://repl.it/qKI/3

Documentation here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html and https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 0):

The `write` function will only handle characters or bytes. To write arbitrary objects, use python's `pickle` library. Write with `pickle.dump()`, read them back with `pickle.load()`.

But if what you're really after is writing something in the same format as your input, you'll have to write out the matrix values and newlines yourself.

```
for line in vals:
    ea.write(line)

ea.close()
```

You've now written a file that looks like `abc.txt`, except that the first row and first character from each line has been removed. (You dropped those when constructing `vals`.)

Somehow I doubt this is what you intended, since you chose to name it `abc_format.txt`, but anyway this is how you write out a list of lines of text.